# Animated GIF on iPhone using OpenGL and GifLib - With Transparent Background!

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, transparent, gif, animated

I am trying to get animated gif to work on iPhone. I searched on Google, had found some useful information from this blog ...

http://www.cuppadev.co.uk/playing-animated-gifs-on-the-iphone

The animations that I try to play is not with simple flipbook style, so I decided to give OpenGL and GifLib a try. I grabbed the code from

https://github.com/jamesu/glgif

This works well with gif without transparent backgrounds, but unfortunately most of my gif files are with transparent background. I am new to OpenGL, I tried to add few lines within the playView function in PlayerView.mm. Something like..

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, GL_MODULATE);

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

But still couldn't remove the white background... I am looking for ways to play animated GIF with transparent background, any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

glgif supports transparent bg gif now.
 https://github.com/jamesu/glgif

Comment: Thanks for this link but try to put some code is much better instead just a link... so answer will be useful even if link is dead.

Comment: @RDC the essential part of that answer is the fact that the mentioned (by the OP) library now supports transparency. I truly am with you in most cases when users answer a question with a link. This case however seems to be a bit different.